# Determine with javascript/jquery the first or last element of php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops

I have this php loop and there's a button on each loop element that removes the element from the loop in the back end then the jquery removes the element on the front end.  Simple. the problem is that I have up and down arrows on each element as well so the user can move the elements(it's a playlist of videos and they can move them in the order they want).

The first and last element in the loop the user is not allowed to move up(if first) or down(if last) and there's a stop symbol.  When I remove the first or last element with the remove button the element before or after stays with two arrows, when now (if let's say I deleted the first row) it should have a stop symbol where the up arrow is.

example:
php/html(too much code to put the up and down arrows but they're in a span tag to left of a href):

```
<?php foreach($playlists->events as $evtIdx => $event) { ?> 
    <a href="#" data-url="<?php echo base_url('/admin/playlists/remove-event/' . $event->id.'/'.$event- 
    event_id.'/'.$event->playlist_id); ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

jquery/ajax call

```
   $(document).on('click','.remove-playlist-event-btn',function(evt){
        var self = $(this);
        var eventElem = self.parents('.event');
        var isFirst = self.data('name');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).data('url'),
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    eventElem.find('.col').html('Course Removed Successfully.');
                    eventElem.find('.col').addClass('text-success');
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        eventElem.fadeOut();
                    },3000);
                }
            }
        });
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
```

So I can put a call on html tag to identify firs or last loop element then get it in the jquery but if a person deletes two in a row it doesn't work.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/first/ and https://api.jquery.com/last/ exist …

Comment: This is probably my answer, let me try to work it and see if I can get it functioning.  Thanks!

Comment: So it works but on the one that gets deleted in three seconds.  So I guess I actually need the one before or after it.  I'll read the documentation but there's probably someway to do like .first() - 1  or something?

Comment: `fadeOut` accepts a callback function, so you could do it in there, after the element was removed. Or use https://api.jquery.com/eq/ to access any element within the selection via its index.

Comment: (Although I don’t think fadeOut actually removes the element, it just sets it to display:none at the end. You could either actually remove it in the callback function first, or combine first/last with https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/ to only select visible elements to begin with.)

Comment: In that case you need `.detach` https://api.jquery.com/detach/

Comment: yea eq is exactly what I need but not working for some reason. probably because the fade out is just display none as you said.  @cBroe  I'll look up detach ncredibleHat  thanks

Comment: How do you designate the stop symbol? Is it css nth classing or something, or are you re-iterating the list to change classes based on position?

Comment: So I just removed the element,  then did.first() and .last() and that worked!  @cBroe if you want to give an answer I'll give it to you.   And IncredibleHat  I did the stop symbol in php, if the index was zero it got a stop symbol,  or if the index was the count of the array minus 1 it got the stop symbol

Comment: although for some reason .last() is not functioning?  I'll figure it out though.